# Python - How to get http response of site

Tags: python

i want to make a python checker to check a http response of a site

i take script from other person

the script like this

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO
import re

curl = pycurl.Curl()

buff = cStringIO.StringIO()
hdr = cStringIO.StringIO()

curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://example.org')
curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, buff.write)
curl.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, hdr.write)
curl.perform()

print "status code: %s" % curl.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
# -> 200

status_line = hdr.getvalue().splitlines()[0]
m = re.match(r'HTTP\/\S*\s*\d+\s*(.*?)\s*$', status_line)
if m:
    status_message = m.groups(1)
else:
    status_message = ''

print "status message: %s" % status_message
# -> "OK"
```

and my problem is, how i make that script can checker site from list in list.txt

example list.txt

```
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.twitter.com
```

Comment: Let us know what you've tried.

Comment: i try to learn in this mailing, im newbie, then i want to learn about programming

Comment: Stackoverflow community is not here to do code for you. Try a python tutorial first.

Comment: okay @PaoloCasciello thanks for your support, i'll do that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read a `.txt` file using [open](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). for eg:

```
import urllib
f = open('list.txt')
for l in f:
    try:
        #for python3.x use: x= urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+l)
        x= urllib.urlopen('http://'+l) 
    except:
        print ('not found')
    else:
        print (x.readlines())
```

Comment: He's asking how to iterate on a list of urls. Your answer is unrelated

Answer (score 0):

you could use a list of website addresses and iterate all the list items

```
websites = ["www.google.com","www.facebook.com","www.twitter.com"]
for website in websites:
      html = urllib2.urlopen(website).read()
      # DO Something
```